# Anchor tags stopped working across pages?

Tags: html, anchor

I have recently created this fanpage for a game. The domain is http://kakeledb.com/

I have a lot of anchors so people can navigate through the pages easier and see which things are connected. All of my anchors were working perfectly for 3 days until a couple hours ago. Now they all work sometimes, and other times they just take me to random parts of the page. (It always takes me to a part before the anchor, so I'm thinking maybe it's a loading issue.

Anyway, here is some of the code.

```
<tr>
                <td style="color:silver;"><div class="item-animation" id="item-2046" style="background:url(items/2046.png) left center;"></div>
                        <a class="anchor" id="RedFabric"> </a>Red Fabric </td>
                <td x="Value: ">650</td>
                <td x="Sources: ">Monsters: Grue, Hell Mage</td>
                <td x="Uses: ">Task: <a href="tasks.html#HellMage">Hell Mages</a> Outfits: <a href="outfits.html#DevilsHunter"><div class="monster-animation" id="outfit-15" style="background:url(outfits/15_base.png) left center;"></div>Devils Hunter</a></td>
              </tr>
```

And the anchor class:

```
.anchor {
display: block;    
position: relative;     
top: -40vh;
visibility: hidden;
```

}

Comment: I don't know how well [Stack snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) would work for this particular issue, but could you try and provide a [mcve]?

Comment: The issue is, the anchors were working fine, until I added more. I'm up to about 200 anchors on the website in total. Would that cause an issue where all anchors become unreliable? If so, how do I do what I want.